# MongoDB countDocuments() very slow in Scala as compared to MongoDB Compass

Tags: mongodb, scala, mongoose, mongodb-query

I am trying to make MongoDB to count documents based on where clause

```
  def headResult(): C = Await.result(observable.head(), Duration(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS))

  val database: MongoDatabase = mongoClient.getDatabase("dbname")
  val collection: MongoCollection[Document] = database.getCollection("tablename")
  val recordCount = collection.countDocuments()
            .headResult()
```

This query returns the count as 766 782 but it takes 2-2.5 seconds. When I make the same query through MongoDB Compass it takes 0.2 seconds .

```
  db.tbltrackerdata.find({},{}).count()
```

Since where clause is dynamic I cannot save prior or maintain any metadata for this.

Comment: So its not the same query. Did you try adding the same filters in MongoDB Compass and see how long that takes? they might not be indexed

Comment: Yes, I kept filters same ... Compass is giving response very fast but with Scala driver only, it is taking some time. I don't how and why

Comment: But you show an empty filter in the compass query?

Comment: so I have updated my question. Also, I doubt that is it because of Scala , it is slow. Somewhere i saw that cursors in scala are comparatively slow with golang code. Is that possible ?

Answer (score 0):

This isn't because of Scala. It's because `db.collection.count({})` or `db.collection.find({}).count()` does not actually fetch the documents. Instead it simply retrieves the number of documents from the collection's metadata.

The `countDocuments` method performs a proper aggregation, which is expected to be slower but also more accurate. You can see it mentioned in the MongoDB documentation here:
https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.countDocuments/#mechanics